# Blue Lines on Kart

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I was recently getting back into Mario Kart Wii, and when I was playing noticed that from time to time, some blue speed lines would appear in front of the kart. Occasionally they would become very numerous and would give the cart a speed boost. What is this, and is there any way to cause it?
[image: Blue Speed lines]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue lines mean you are [drafting](https://www.mariowiki.com/Slipstream).

To do this, you need to follow behind another player. If you do it right, the lines will appear. If you can remain in that state for long enough, you'll gain a small boost.

[Drafting is also used in the real world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_(aerodynamics)), though it works a bit differently than in Mario Kart.